# PHP SQL Query Where IN array of arrays

Tags: php, sql, arrays

How can a SQL query be run to:
Select fields Where `ID_del_hotel` and `Ocupacion` and `HO` **>=** matches variables IN `Array[ID_del_hotel, Ocupacion, HO]`

```
$array=

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID_del_hotel] => 45
            [Ocupacion] => SGL
            [HO] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID_del_hotel] => 44
            [Ocupacion] => DBL
            [HO] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ID_del_hotel] => 44
            [Ocupacion] => QDP
            [HO] => 3
        )

)
```

Comment: loop the array to build the query

Comment: Your question is not clear. Show your database table schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the array to build an IN clause with the IDs

MySQL

```
WHERE db_id IN (45,46,47)
```

Comment: and the other variables?

Comment: How much do you care about DB speed? You could do a CONCAT on the values and be a bit dirty. CONCAT(id, "-", name, "-", etc) IN (valuelist) / however if you do it this way you will lose indexing performance.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your query.

```
    $arr = Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [ID_del_hotel] => 45
                [Ocupacion] => SGL
                [HO] => 1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [ID_del_hotel] => 44
                [Ocupacion] => DBL
                [HO] => 2
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [ID_del_hotel] => 44
                [Ocupacion] => QDP
                [HO] => 3
            )

    );
$i=0;
foreach($arr as $value){
   $sql = "Select * from Tbl_name where ID_del_hotel=".$value['ID_del_hotel']." and HO>=".$value['Ho'];
if(mysql_query($sql)){
   $resultArray[$i] = $value;
   $i++;
}
}
print_r($resultArray);
```

$resultArray has the array values matching with the query.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your hotel IDs are unique (they should be), you can do this:

```
$arr = [
    [
        "ID_del_hotel" => 45,
        "Ocupacion" => "SGL",
        "HO" => 1
    ],
    [
        "ID_del_hotel" => 44,
        "Ocupacion" => "DBL",
        "HO" => 2
    ],
    [
        "ID_del_hotel" => 44,
        "Ocupacion" => "QDP",
        "HO" => 3
    ]
];

$ids = array_map(function ($a) {
    return $a['ID_del_hotel'];
}, $arr);

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE ID_del_hotel = (' . implode(',', $ids) . ')';

// output result
var_dump($sql);
```